# Reactjs: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm getting an undefined reading of url and other product.{items} when I reload the browser to run this piece of code.

```
 const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProduct = async ()=>{
            try{
                const res = await commerce.products.retrieve(id);
                setProduct(res);
            }catch{}
        };
        fetchProduct();
    },[id]);


  return (
    <Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <ImgContainer>
               <Image src={product.image.url}/>
            </ImgContainer>
            <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{product.name}</Title>                
            </InfoContainer>
        </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Might be you are not getting the response in product or the components you are using are not importing if you share the complete code it will be better

Comment: try it : ```product?.name```

Comment: Try logging the res variable. `const res = await commerce.products.retrieve(id);` I suspect that it is undefined. And after you are setting the state, you are reading if by  `product.name`. So if it is undefined, you can add a condition that if it is not undefined, only then set the state. For EX;- `if (res) setProduct(res);`

Comment: Please check if you are accessing `url` correctly. What is the response skeleton you are getting from API? Is it an array or nested complex object?